# ckeditor bringing html file

Tags: html, ckeditor

Hello I have used ckEditor and I am trying to bring this html form to display. Like this.

[image]

For this code, I used

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor">

  <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" style="height:850px; width:780px; background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/BMoWEBO.png')">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</textarea>
```

(I have cut most of the html for this question)

When I tried to open with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor">

  <div ng-include="'../forms/promo_email_form'"></div>

</textarea>
```

It just gave blank space.

I want to bring this html file and save it so I can access to edited version of html file.

So the question is:

How can I open html so I can view through ckEditor automatically?